# Pandas join on column based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

I have read several other SO questions with (almost) the same problem, altho this is a bit different.

I have a dataframe

```py
#df_animals

animal | weight | id
-------+--------+----
"cow"     50       1
"cow"     45       2
"pig"     30       1
"pig"     25       2
```

and another dataframe

```py
"df_cow_price

id | price
---+------
1    100
2    70
```

and I want to join `df_cow_price` onto `df_animals` joining on `id` but only where `animal=="cow"`.

Right now my work-around is by filtering on `animal=="cow"`, remove that filtered data from the dataframe, join on the filtered dataframe and concat the filtered and unfiltered dataframe.

But isn't there a way to do that in "one go" i.e something like this pseudo-code

```py
df_total = pd.merge(df_animals,df_cow_price, left_on="id", right_on="id", filter_left = df_animals["animal"]=="cow")

animal | weight | id | price
-------+--------+----+------
"cow"     50       1   100
"cow"     45       2   70
"pig"     30       1   None
"pig"     25       2   None
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible like need in `merge`, need postprocessing or postprocessing like:

```
df_total = pd.merge(df_animals, df_cow_price, on="id", how='left')
df_total.loc[df_total["animal"]!="cow", 'price'] = np.nan
```

Or:

```
df_total1=pd.merge(df_animals[df_animals["animal"]=="cow"],df_cow_price, on="id",how='left')

df_total2=df_animals[df_animals["animal"]!="cow"]

df_total = pd.concat([df_total1, df_total2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks - good point! I then assume there isn't some kind of filter-function i.e we cannot do it w/o doing some pre/post-processing of the dataframe (that's mainly my question)

Comment: @CutePoison - hmmm, it is not possible in `merge` like need.